# How might one programmatically set the link for all images in all posts?

Tags: images, filters, hooks, links

Every post on my Wordpress site contains at least one image (in the content, not as an attachment).  Each post also contains a custom field with a URL.

I'd like to programmatically modify all posts such that all `<img />` tags within the post are wrapped with an anchor tag, pointing to the URL in that post's custom field.

I realize that this would be trivial with JavaScript, but I'd really prefer to do it at the PHP level if at all possible.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** This is what I've been trying to mess around with, but I don't know WordPress well enough to know if this is the best strategy.

```
function give_linked_images_class($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){
  if ( preg_match('/(<img.*\/>)/', $html) )
  {
    $url = get_post_meta( $id, 'URL', true );
    $html = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $html . '</a>';
  }
  return $html;
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_class');
```

Comment: I've tried adding a filter on the `image_send_to_editor` function, similarly to this code snippet: https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/add-rel-or-class-to-image-links#post-20672

Comment: try using velvet urls https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/